# Conditionally set @Activeprofile before database test in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application with a test class that tests some crud operations and services against my mongodb. Until now everything was done on my machine (mongo was on localhost). When running tests I set the active profile to "test" to skip some authentication methods used in my services. Right now we are setting up a prod environment where mongo is on a dedicated server and I have setup different profiles using different application.properties files. That part works fine but when running the tests on the hosted environment the tests fail because mongo is not on localhost. I looked around a lot for some kind of solution.

My idea is to somehow before the tests are run to check if the active profile is "prod" and then set the active profile to something like "test-prod" that uses the hosted mongo, and if the active profile is "default or dev" set active profile to "test" that runs against localhost.

Any ideas or solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you running tests in prod? Is it a prod-like build environment? Coz you need to run tests only on build right?

Comment: To find out if it's prod environment or not, you might need to use an environment variable or have another property in your config to specify the environment and then set the active profile for the test accordingly. Doesn't look like a good design to run tests in prod though.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it is a Maven project so the tests will be run when building and this will not happen on my machine. I just want to skip needing to change settings on my machine while developing locally :)

Comment: For your requirement, it is advisable not to dynamically set the @ActiveProfile as it would be kind of a hack and unnecessary config that you would need to add.

Comment: I see, any suggestions then? Because I can add a .properties file for my test profile that points at the mongoserver, that works fine but I would need to outcomment it everytime I want to run tests on my local machine (Or thats what I can come up with right now at least :)).

Comment: Yes that's what would be advisable. Have a profile with local Mongo server and another with the prod Mongo server. Commit the code with the the prod test profile, but locally use the local test profile. See my answer :)

Comment: ok I will, just waiting a bit more to see if something genius pops up otherwise I'll accept :) Thanks!

Comment: Sure that's better :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use resolver to dynamically set profile based on for example environment variable

```
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = MyActiveProfileResolver.class)
class MyTest { ... }
```

And profile resolver:

```
public class MyActiveProfilesResolver  implements ActiveProfilesResolver{
  @Override
  public String[] resolve(Class<?> testClass) {
      Map<String, String> env =  System.getenv();
      String profile;
      if (env.hasKey("TEST_ENV")) {
          profile = env.get("TEST_ENV");
      } else {
          // it is more convenient to have this as a default
          // to be used in dev env and override it on test env
          profile = "local-test";
      }
      return new String[]{profile};
  }
}
```

Create three profiles `test`, `local-test` and `prod`. Resolver should return `test` or `local-test` depending on the env variable `TEST_ENV`.

Comment: Thanks! sounds good, could you please provide a small example setting an active profile using a resolver?

Comment: @Smastik sure. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use environment variables. Instead of providing an url in your application-test.yaml, define a variable like : ${MONGO_TEST_URL}

You will be able to run your jar using java -jar -DMONGO_TEST_URL=localhost or whatever address you want to use.

Comment: Doesn't look like that's what the OP wants. Looks like the OP wants to dynamically set the @ActiveProfile annotation based on the environment to run the tests.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. He must use other ways to achieve what he want to do.

Comment: Exactly that's what I've commented on the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to dynamically change the @ActiveProfile based on the environment since it would need you to add extra config to find out which environment it is and set the @ActiveProfile for the tests based on that. The extra config and work that you do would not be a good design and would be unnecessary. If running the tests on your local is the only hiccup, I would advise you to always set the @ActiveProfile to `test-prod` and change it locally to `test` whenever you are developing on your machine. Do be careful not to commit the local @ActiveProfile though :)

Comment: Thats what I'm doing right now and was hoping to solve it but if it's a hack as mentioned earlier, maybe I should stick to this was for the moment. :))

Comment: @Smastik yeah sure. Coz for what you had asked earlier, you would need the extra config of finding out what environment you are in, which is not worth adding.

Answer (score 0):

Same as [@romal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52101540/6654475) but a bit smaller, using `System.getProperty()` instead of `getEnv()`.

```
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = MyActiveProfileResolver.class)
class MyTest { ... }
```

And

```
public class MyActiveProfileResolver implements ActiveProfilesResolver {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String[] resolve(@NotNull Class<?> testClass) {
        return new String[]{System.getProperty("testEnvt", "dev")};
    }
}
```